# Custom Authentication and ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an internal web app being built in `ASP.NET 4`. We are stuck with using an authentication API built by another team. If a user to the site is authenticated successfully for the site I would like to give them access to the entire site.

In `ASP.NET` WebForm days I just used to keep a custom User object in session. If that object was null I knew the user wasn't authenticated. Is there a similar but improved method for this in `MVC`. I don't want to have to build my own provider of the ASP.NET Membership model if possible. What is the simplest way of doing this?

Comment: Can you not just set the authentication ticket manually after your call to your legacy API?

Comment: If the `FormsAuthenticationTicket` is set, you can use `Request.IsAuthenticated` and `User.Identity` to determine whether the user is logged in. Also the `Authorize` attribute will work.

Comment: FYI, handling authentication in session is a very bad idea, it's insecure (cookie is not encrypted and easily stolen), and prone to failure as session can be recycled at any time.  Use FormsAuthentication instead

Comment: Great feedback. Thanks TheKingDave, Henk, Mystere

Comment: Sometimes the solution is on another question, someone already did a very flexible solution here on on stackoverflow without need of hard coded role name , there is the complete code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9043831/authorizeattribute-with-roles-but-not-hard-coding-the-role-values/9048151#9048151

Comment: @BuddyJoe, I'm doing the same thing.  Do you mind if I ask what solution you went with?

Comment: @HenkMollema I am using `FormsAuthenticationTicket`, but I could not use `User.Identity` and `Authorize` is not working

Answer (score 45):

You can use `Forms Authentication` in conjuction with `Authorize` attibute as follows,

To restrict access to a view :

Add the AuthorizeAttribute attribute to the action method declaration, as shown below,

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

Configuring Forms Authentication in web.config

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
     <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

Login Post Action:
Set Authentication cookie if user is valid

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(User model, string returnUrl)
{
        //Validation code

        if (userValid)
        {
             FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, false);
        }
}
```

Log off Action:

```
public ActionResult LogOff()
{
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

Comment: Do I have to put [Authorize] on every Controller method in my entire app? I only want to open up two controller methods to anonymous users (~/Account/Login GET and POST). Seems like there should be a better way. Do this require a filter? custom attribute? Thanks for your help. +1

Comment: In this case have a look here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2011/05/02/securing-your-asp-net-mvc-3-application.aspx

Comment: Why can't the new ASP Identity be as simple as `FormsAuthentication`? https://www.asp.net/identity

Answer (score 5):

You probably want to have a custom [authorization filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute%28v=vs.108%29.aspx). Here's an example: [Custom filters in MVC](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/426766/Custom-Filters-in-MVC-Authorization-Action-Result). You can then apply this filter globally on app start (using `RegisterGlobalFilters`).

```
public class LegacyAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute
{
  public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
  {
    if (HttpContext.Current.Session["User"] == null)
      base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(actionContext);
  }
}
```

Then in your `global.asax` you'd have something like this:

```
GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new LegacyAuthorize());
```

Comment: Overriding the Authorize attribute can be dangerous especially if only validating session.  Session Id is not re-generated, which can lead to session hijack via XSS etc.  http://blog.securityps.com/2013/06/session-fixation-forms-authentication.html and https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/899918

Answer (score 4):

You can try with something like this:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, rememberMe);
```

to set the cookie for authenticated user, then just use the `[Authorize]` attribute on the Controller or Action that need authentication.

Try googling on the subject for further info, you will find a lot of stuff on authentication and authorization in MVC.

Answer (score 1):

Everything you could do in forms you can do in MVC, just set the session variable in the controller login action.

Or you can do this:
    In the login action add `formsauthentication.setauthcookie("username")`

After this any action with the [Authorize] keyword will allow the current user in.

Answer (score -2):

You can do the Session Authentication by simply putting a session variable value when the login is successful. Eg

```
public ActionResult Index(Models.Login login)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Dal.Login dLogin = new Dal.Login();
            string result = dLogin.LoginUser(login);
            if (result == "Success")
                Session["AuthState"] = "Authenticated";
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Now the trick is that you should have a common layout page of all the views to which you have to check for authentication. And in this layout page just do a razor check like this -

```
<body>
    @if (Session["AuthState"] != "Authenticated")
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/login");
    }
    // other html
</body>
```

I have been using this method in my application admin panel.

Comment: Just a heads up that this method is dangerous and can result in a session fixation or session hijack attack.

The session id is never updated.

See this article for a quick explanation of the downsides. 

tl;dr; you need an authentication cookie that is unique to a logged in session and ideally tied to the session.

http://blog.securityps.com/2013/06/session-fixation-forms-authentication.html