# MVC 5 Custom ActionFilter not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to implement basic authentication to a service using this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20144364/basic-authentication-in-asp-net-mvc-5) as a template.

For some reason the action filter is never applied to my controllers and I have no idea why.

My controller:

```
[BasicAuthenticationManager("username", "password")]
public class DataController : ApiController
{
    private DataEntities db = new DataEntities();

    // GET: api/Data

    //[BasicAuthenticationManager]
    public IHttpActionResult GetvwData()
    {
        return Json(db.vwData);
    }
}
```

My filter:

```
public class BasicAuthenticationManager : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    protected string userName { get; set; }
    protected string password { get; set; }

    public BasicAuthenticationManager(string userName, string password)
    {
        this.userName = userName;
        this.password = password;
    }
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {

        var req = filterContext.HttpContext.Request;
        var auth = req.Headers["Authorization"];

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(auth))
        {
            var credentials = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(auth.Substring(6))).Split(':');
            var user = new { Name = credentials[0], Pass = credentials[1] };
            if (user.Name == userName && user.Pass == password) return;
        }

        filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
    }
}
```

I don't get an error messaage and the filter is recogniced by code autocompletion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inherit from System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute instead of ActionFilterAttribute.
You can override the IsAuthorized method.

```
protected override bool IsAuthorized(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
{
    //Auth logic
    //return whether user is authorized or not.
}
```