# Sitecore with iis Forms Authentication and coding Basic Authentication

Tags: sitecore, basic-authentication, form-authentication

Currently I used 
[Basic authentication in ASP.NET MVC 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20144364/basic-authentication-in-asp-net-mvc-5/27348911#27348911) to makes my sitecore website has login requirement, in iis Authentication the "Anonymous" and "Forms" are enabled.

But when the Forms Authentication is disable, I am unable to login Sitecore back office, therefore it must be enabled. On the other hand, the page will redirect to specify page directly without asking login information.

My question is how can I make it works using coding basic authentication and iis forms authentication.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Useing [Basic authentication in ASP.NET MVC 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20144364/basic-authentication-in-asp-net-mvc-5)

And configure Form Authentication redirect the page to the page being restrict("/" only). Then both are working.