# What are type of logins in asp.net MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, active-directory, single-sign-on

There are some kind of logins in asp.net MVC. for instance there is individual or windows login. I saw some kind of login popup in TFS server that you can see it in following photo:

[TFS login popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4Zxk.png)

My question is what is this kind of login called? and how can I implement some sort of this in my asp.net MVC website that use active directory to login?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's called "Basic Authentication".

To make the browser ask for the basic authentication credentials, your server has to return a 401 HTTP response with the correct header:

```
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="basic"
```

You can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20144364/basic-authentication-in-asp-net-mvc-5) full examples how to implement basic authentication in ASP.NET MVC.